# Monodroid cleartask flag available?

Tags: xamarin.android

I need to run an activity and remove all the other activities for my application to save memory. I have seen in the sdk that the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK does exactly this but I can't find it in the ActivityFlags enum in monodroid.

Is this possible to be done with monodroid?

Comment: This answers it pretty well for pre-12 api http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154743/android-clearing-the-full-activity-stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ActivityFlags.ClearTask](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T:Android.Content.ActivityFlags) is available in Mono for Android. However, Android didn't introduce this flag until API version 11, so I'm guessing that you're targeting a previous version. In order to use this flag, you'll need to update the minimum version of Android you target to 3.1, which is configurable in the project's properties page.

**Edit**: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427720/clearing-activity-stack) has some other approaches you can take to do this on previous versions of Android.

Comment: I can't use Api 11. My requirements are 2.3 maximum. Is there any other alternative?