# Close all running activities in an android application?

Tags: android, android-activity

I create one application and never use finish() for each activity. If my user clicks on the logout button it goes to the previous page.

How can I close my previous activity and close the application?

Answer (score 6):

This is one workaround that i have tried and it worked for me perfectly.

**SOLUTION-1**

```
this.finish();//try activityname.finish instead of this
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

use this in the activity where you want to exit from your application....

==================================================================================
Above code helps to resume your app where you last left off.

**SOLUTION-2**

If you want to exit from the application and also close all running activities you need to use.

```
onActivityResult()
```

For eg- suppose there are 3 activities A,B,C you navigate from A->B->C and at C you want to close all activities then use following sample.

Activity A

```
public class A extends Activity {
int Finish = 100;
Button launch_second;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    launch_second = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_second_act);
    launch_second.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent second = new Intent(A.this,
                    B.class);
            startActivityForResult(second, Finish);
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 100:
        this.finish();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Activity B

```
public class B extends Activity {
private Button launch_next;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_main);
    launch_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_third_activity);
    launch_next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent third = new Intent(B.this,C.class);
            startActivityForResult(third, 100);
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 100:
        setResult(requestCode);
        this.finish();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

Activity C

```
public class C extends Activity {
Button kill_app;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.third_main);
    kill_app = (Button)findViewById(R.id.kill_app_btn);
    kill_app.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            C.this.finish();
            setResult(100);

        }
    });

}

}
```

**SOLUTION-3**

There is method available `finishAffinity()` call it from any activity,all previous activities will get destroyed.

Comment: This close the app but doesn't finish the activities. If you reopen the app you don't go to the main activity.

Comment: @BraisGabin I have updated the answer ,check the updated answer,hope it might help for some others looking for the solution

Comment: @SagarG., this one will make the "Back Button" not working as usual. INstead it will make the button work as "Close All and Out". And that's not the effect we want to get. How to solve it out?

Comment: SOLUTION-1 is not working for clear all activity from stack, it resume from last stored activity and solution 2 is long process.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Sam Janz answer is cleaner than this method. Use the [intent flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) to your advantage

When the user presses log out:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyHomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putBooleanExtra("finishApplication", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in MyHomeActivity (Your start activity) [in onResume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29):

```
if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("finishApplication", false){
   finish();
}
```

This way you don't have to have checks in all your activity's only the Home activity.

---

Dirtier option:

Create a static boolean variable in a singleton somewhere (probably in a class that extends application);

```
public static boolean loggingOut = false;
```

When the user presses log out set this to true and call finish on that activity.

```
YourApplication.loggingOut = true;
finish();
```

In each [activity in onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29)

```
if(loggingOut){
   finish();
}
```

Ensure you set this boolean back to false in your main/start up activity:

```
if(loggingOut){
   finish();
   YourApplication.loggingOut = false;
}
```

If you also want the back button to do it, [override onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29), that would then also do

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
     YourApplication.loggingOut = true;
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*use [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) for each activity*

1) [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle)

2) [Shutting down Activity and managing Activities lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)

3) The same question [answered in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007998/on-logout-clear-activity-history-stack-preventing-back-button-from-opening-l) (2 approaches - Broadcast Receiver (+1) and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Comment: Hi thanks for reply i use finish() on each activity but then my mobile back button is not work if i press back it close my application

Comment: it depends on what you're trying to achieve. You want to click logout and close your program, but in any other case, when hitting the back button, you want the previous Activities to be visible?

Comment: yes, actually i have login and logout facility for user so i want when user is login he can navigate in my app easily using mobile back button or using menu but when click on logout that time i want to close all activity and he can not be enter in to previous page without login again... and thank hovanessyan for giving me your valuable time..:-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your replies. I solved my problem.

Solution: I write a file with some data and when the user clicks logout, I remove data from that file and `finish()` current activity, and all in previous activity I write code in `onResume()` I read file and if it is blank or null `finish()` so in that it will close all your activity and your application get close. Thank you for the great help.

Comment: abusing a file with arbitrary data as a flag is probably not the best design. You could at least make it a boolean on some singleton or some such.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
startActivity(mainIntent);
```

Description:

```
public static Intent makeRestartActivityTask (ComponentName mainActivity)
```

Make an Intent that can be used to re-launch an application's task in its base state. This is like makeMainActivity(ComponentName), but also sets the flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == btnAtGlanceBack) {
            Intent backIntent = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
            startActivity(backIntent);

        } else if (v == btnAtGlanceLogOut) {
            Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(this, GlobalScholarLogin.class);
            logoutIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(logoutIntent);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general android main stack for all you activity your launching and remove it based on the way you call to  next activity.
If you want to clear all activity  set this flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`  while launching activity in order to clean up previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

To clear whole stack which is tracking your activities in android you can use following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyHomeActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

put this line of code in your application
System.exit(2);

Answer (score 0):

you can use this
`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivity(intent);`

from this question answer 
[How to exit from the application and show the home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/android-exit-application-code)

Answer (score 0):

you can add a List in Application that save every activity you created.
and when you exit, you just need to finish all activity in the list.