# Android 2.2 (API 8) Logging Out

Tags: android

I have an app that will have multiple activities open.

Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C

I want to logout and close all open activities. I have read many different links that describes how to do this.

[On logout, clear Activity history stack, preventing "back" button from opening logged-in-only Activites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007998/on-logout-clear-activity-history-stack-preventing-back-button-from-opening-l)

[Close all running activities in an android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615431/close-all-running-activities-in-an-android-application)

The issue for this however is that the Intent Flags only work with API level 11 and above. I have an app that I would like to be made available for API level 8 and above. I know that it goes way back but what is the best way to accomplish this for API level 8?

Or should I just give in and make the minimum level 11?

Comment: Don't give in! There's still a lot of Android 2.3 devices out there.

Comment: The alternative using `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` works fine even on API level 8

Comment: Does it broadcast it to all open activities when the activity is closed? Does it affect performance at all?

Answer (score 2):

Intent intent  = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);``

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
   void signOut() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("finish", true);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // To clean up all activities *not necessary*
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
   }
```

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9580057/1932105)

Comment: Unfortunately no that didn't work for me. Same exact results as before :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you can do one thing get ProcessID of your application and in onDestroy() kill that process. Thats it from this link [How to force stop my android application programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100728/how-to-force-stop-my-android-application-programatically)

```
int pid=android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

you can use alternative told by one of user here  using startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult() works fine even on API level 8.

For this u need to use

```
 startActivityForResult() instead of startActivty. and onActivtyResult() for you work.
```

Answer (score 0):

you say "I want to logout and close all open activities." , Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP works on API Level 8 , I have incorporated Logout functionality ,that way in app that is already in store, but there is one difference if I understand you correctly , logout goes to LoginActivity , logout does not kill process or something as this goes against concept of Android. Anyway you can even do this also when you do this as suggested above:

```
  void logout() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("finish", true);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
   }
```

And then in LoginActivity you can search for "finish" boolean in extra in onCreate method and finish that activity too.

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("finish", false)) finish();
}
```