# In android how to close entire application with logout button

Tags: android

I have activity A, B & C and I went from A-> C-> B-> at final activity I have one logout button, and on click of it, how to finish entire application with all previous activities and its stacks.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615431/close-all-running-activities-in-an-android-application/8615527#8615527

Comment: Just call `Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                startMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(startMain);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class)
.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
finish();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you have session, so please clear your session before your intent have been called.

Comment: As you can see, that will go (from `MainActivity`) to `LoginActivity` but, with these flags: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` or etc, for an `Activity`, not for an `Application`.

Comment: you also need to pass more two flags with intent will help you out.

Comment: Yes, but See: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` , `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` this is for an activity which you finished it with `finish();` means, something like restarting an `Activity` not an `Application`.and look at the title: how to **close entire application** with logout button

Answer (score 1):

```
this.finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple,  you have to `finish()` all of your active `intents`.
So either make sure you only have 1 intent open at the time, or finish multiple intents at the final activity

Comment: `finish();` will close an `Activity` , but will certainly not close the entire app with certainty - refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32570741/4409113

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that. But the refered SO seems like a nice answer to this question.

Comment: Yeah, look at this answer from CommonsWare too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2034238/4409113

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is:

```
getActivity().finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Take a look at this question:

[How to quit android application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically)

And also: [Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238)

**Which says:**

> but Android can very well totally destroy your app whenever it feels
>   like it".. This is true for all modern OSs

So i think that is not a good way, though.