# Android: OutOfMemory error and the backstack

Tags: java, android, task, out-of-memory, heap-memory

the following sheet represents the working flow in the application this question is about.

[image: workflow]

I ran into problems with OutOfMemory Errors, mostly because users were able to switch from activity B to activity D multiple times (They are showing different content for every attempt), without the previous activity being destroyed. This led into a very large backstack resulting in an OutOfMemory error.

To avoid this, I followed the recommendation to add parent activites to the manifest and create new backstacks with the TaskStackBuilder class:

```
void openDFromB()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityD.class);
    TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
        .addParentStack(ActivityD.class)
        .addNextIntent(i)
        .startActivities();
}
```

If a user now switches from activity B to D, MainMenu, A and B are destroyed and a new Backstack (MainMenu, C, D) is created.
This solves my memory problems for api level greater 10, but unfortunately the TaskStackBuilder does not create backstacks for devices pre api 11.

Any idea what to do in order to avoid users stacking infinite amounts of activities prior api 11? Is this even possible or should I try to free as many resources as possible in onPause to gain a maximum amount of stacked activities before OoM?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zabri answer is good, but i would propose another probably is better:
You dont close every activity, but when you are opening a new activity that has been open before, you tell the system that it can clear the way back and reopen that one, of course with a new intent and all the new data that you need.

So, if you do A - B - D - B - D - B, instead of having that big stack,you will have

1. A - B
2. A - B - D
3. A - B
4. A - B - D
5. A - B

So, if you do C - D - B - D - B - D, your stack will be

1. C - D
2. C - D - B
3. C - D
4. C - D - B
5. C - D

and so on. 
In this way, i think the stack actually reflects what the user can have in mind, and also navigation is very logic, you don't even need to captre back button to have the navigation making sense, (of course you can do it if you want a more specific user experience)

The code to achieve this, is:
create a function that receives a class (something like ActivityD.class), there you create an intent, with the flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and then when you need to open an activity, just call this function. You dont care about if the activity is in the stack or not. If it isnt,it is created normally.

```
 protected void startActivity(Class<?> clase) {
    final Intent i = new Intent(this, clase);
    int flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP;
    flags |= Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;
    i.setFlags(flags);
    startActivity(i);
}


startActivity(ActivityD.class);
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),yourActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Another solution is-

Setting `android:noHistory="true"` on the activity in your manifest file will remove an activity from the stack whenever it is navigated away from.

But the most appropriate way is to call `finish()` method whenever you start new activity like in the following sample code-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

You can also create custom Broadcast receiver and register it in every activity which can be fired on event of your choice. [For more help you can check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736594/what-is-the-right-way-to-clear-background-activity-activites-from-stack).

Answer (score 3):

May be your application having memory leaks and due to that older activities not getting reclaim by the GC and eventually getting heap size increase every-time activity switch occurs.

**How to find leaks?** 
Please watch: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

**References:**

1. http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html.
2. http://kohlerm.blogspot.in/2009/07/eclipse-memory-analyzer-10-useful.html

Comment: activities never get destroyed by Android to reclaim heap space. this is a common misunderstanding. it only destroys activities if app is paused and system runs low on memory.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how it works with the Navigation Drawer, but I was creating an Android application some time ago which started with a loading screen and then moved to the main activity of the app. Since I didn't need/want the user ever to go back to the loading screen, I just called `finish()` before moving to the main activity. Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

And then, when the user pressed the *back* button from the main activity, they didn't get to the loading activity, but to wherever they were even before that.

So you could also try to do this:

```
void openDFromB()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityD.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

As I said, I have never implemented a Navigation Drawer, but something tells me that doing this might break its whole behaviour. Also, calling `finish()` in an activity is such a basic concept that I would be surprised if you hadn't tried it already. :) But still, I am posting it as a shot in the dark, just in case it helps you. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hello you can try to add the following statement in your manifest file under application tag:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Also make sure your `android:targetSdkVersion` is 14.