# Remove a specific previous activity from stack

Tags: java, android, android-activity, stack

In my app have some Activities, but in a particular point 've the stack
otherActivities -> A -> B -> newA
Now, i've some weird things to do:
-if I'm in B and I press the back button i will return in A.
-if I'm in newA and press back I don't want to see neither A and B, but return to the activity stack (already Achieved to skip B)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469023/android-outofmemory-error-and-the-backstack/20680484#20680484