# Activities on stack after backpressed, Memory usage

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, crash, activity-finish

I have a few specific Questions.

I´m developing a touristic app. It works great, but after a long time launching new activities it crashes. I used the debug and i realized it uses a lot of memory, it is like the activities don´t closes altought I call.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}
```

after removing some static variables and using in every new activity this flag

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

memory space is relieved. App performance looks good, altought it uses a lot of images and listviews because i used Holders

However, in the main activity i placed the same onBackPressed code, but after pressing it the app is not closed, the memory usage is decreased but i have my doubts

Here is my Questions

1. Is the app really closing?
2. It still there because is a recent app?
3. The memory usage decreasing means that the activity FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and onBackPressed() is Working?
4. Is this the
           right way to manage the activities to finish() ?

Comment: See this if it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469023/android-outofmemory-error-and-the-backstack/20680484#20680484

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html Check this out it may help you with the memory issue.
- Secondly, if your app makes use of internet connection, do check out your code for checking the internet connection to be present or not.
- Thirdly, it seems that you have written all the code in the onCreate() method, hence the app is taking a long time. Make use of AsyncTask.
- Fourthly, whenever you call finish() method, the app closes. So it is the right way.

Comment: I use Asynctask, but i call it from onCreate(), Is better to call it in onStart() ? or onResume()?
Thank you.

Comment: After onBackpressed in the first activity the monitor still shows the aplication using memory, it seems like the app is not finished

Comment: No, you should call it from onCreate() itself and not onStart() or onResume(). The onCreate() is the main thread on which all the activites run.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342761/how-do-you-use-intent-flag-activity-clear-top-to-clear-the-activity-stack   maybe this link could help you.

Comment: Ok. Just added my AsyncTasks to the onCreate() method. 
@void Adi , i read the article, as I understand the onBackPressed() will clear the top of activities stack and make a new intent of a previous activity as a new activity, it works good, but in my situation this is not proper, the previous activity have downloaded a lot of images in a listview  and make a new activity of it will mean use a new internet connection and download the images again.
Because of that i prefer not re-Create an activity that is the same as one I have already created.
Thank you all for your comments :D