# Android - Finish intermediate activity

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I have a main activity (A) that starts a new activity (B) that calls a third activity (C). When pressing a button on activity C, i would like to return to activity A and also close activity B.

**Schema:**

A -(opens)> B -(opens)> C

When pressing a button on activity C I only want to have activity A, so I need to kill B and C.

On Activity C i can just call `finish()`.

What to do with activity B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When you open activity C from Activity B call finish() on Activity B so that when you call finish() on Activity C it will go to Activity A but not B because B is not the stack anymore.

OR

> Call Activity A from Activity C with the below intent flags.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

These flags will clear the entire Activity stack

Comment: 1. What if user wants to change some details filled in Activity B and for that presses back button from Activity C? 2. What if there are other activities in queue before Activity A (e.g. X -> Y -> A -> B -> C) and user just want finish activities B and C?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to finish an activity from another activity, check these two answers

[How to finish an activity from other activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511216/android-how-to-finish-an-activity-from-other-activity)

[What is the right way to clear background activity/activites from stack ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736594/what-is-the-right-way-to-clear-background-activity-activites-from-stack)