# Clear Activities history stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to clear activities history stack, when user click on `logout button` even tried with the `IntentFlag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` but no luck. Have look at my scenario mentioned below.

1) Login screen (calling finish)

2) First screen (not calling finish)

3) second screen (not calling finish)

4) Third screen (not calling finish)

5) log out screen (It will open login screen, and get finish)

To achieve my goal m using below code,

**Login screen**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

*login back event*

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
            this.finish();
        }else{
            this.finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**First screen**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

**Second screen**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(SecondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

**Third screen**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(ThirdActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); 
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

Problem is, when I click log out, it goes to login activity and when I click back button it goes to second activity.

why its not finishing activities and also why its goes to `second activity` if it maintaining the stack then it should goes to `first activity` instead second one when I click back from `login screen`,  don't know what sort of thing I missing.

**Updated**

Everything is working fine if I remove `finish()` while calling intent from login screen, but I don't wanna keep in stack login screen.

your suggestion are appriciable.

Comment: try to use android:nohistory="true" in the activities you want... and try to finish if you wont re use the screens again.

Comment: did you tried with  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) ???

Comment: @Rajesh yes, but no luck

Comment: why are you not using finish in first, second ,third screens?

Comment: @Rajesh I have keep open when I click back from logout.

Comment: This is work for me
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3008684/3758898

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can Do a Trick for this Question. I have Used it and works fine with me.

Write below Line of Code **inside your ThirdActivity onclick**.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(ThirdActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("GO", false);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

After Write Below Code inside your **OnCreate of FirstActivity Class:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Getting the Value of GO
        GO = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("GO");

             if(GO){
        setContentView(R.layout.form_data);
            ...
            // Here your Code for this Activity 
            ...
            }else{
            Intent intent=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
           finish();
           }
}
```

**Also put Extra value of GO as true while calling FirstActivity from MainActivity as Below**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
                 intent.putExtra("GO", true);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

Hope it will Solve your Problem.

Comment: thanks its also one of trick, but I did something in simply way! I answered check it.

Answer (score 3):

Change the intent flat `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` to `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` and try. I hope it works and helps you.

Clear Top will work only when you have Activity you are calling is in the BackStack. As LoginActivity is not in the BackStack, Activities are not cleared.

add `android:noHistory="true"` for LoginActivity in `AndroidManifest.xml` and try. I am giving this update after seeing your updated question.

Comment: Great. android:noHistory="true" is very important.

Answer (score 0):

`Third screen`

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
   {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(ThirdActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);          
            intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

Comment: @RobinHood have you used `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);`?. Your code sounds perfect i dunno why it's not working. Just try to clean up the project if same problem persist.

Comment: I did everything yet not working, can give me logical reasoning of your answer?

Comment: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME` That is, pressing back from the task will always return the user to home even if that was not the last activity they saw.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I got one solution, anyway! Its fulfilled my goal, make the static object of the activity in its own activity, and while logout `object.finish()` for all activities, it working fine.

*Below is my trick to achieve my goal*

In first activity  declare `public static FirstActivity first;` and within `onCreate` assing `first=this;`  same thing I did for others activities too and while log out, did like below.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                FirstActivity.first.finish();
                SecondActivity.second.finish();

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```