# cleare activity stack between 2 given activities when do not keep activities flag is set in developer settings

Tags: android

I have an application in which i move from activity A->B->C->D.
Now i want that when i press a button on D my stack should be A->D. i have done this from android API level 8 to 10 but on android 4.0 i have "**do not keep activities**" settings that kill my activities when in background thus making Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        and  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK useless as my activity a is not alive.

How can i handle this situation.
Any help is greaty appriciated.

Comment: if that activity has no history then when you go aback from D to A, A will be created again.

Comment: if i launch an activity with NOHISTORY flag then if user presses home button on that activity to minimize it the activity is killed and when i launch my app back from home i land up in different activity as my front activity is killed.

Comment: There is an easy way for API >= 16.

Comment: but the issue with me is that i need this code to be running on API level 9 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Do not keep activities I think it is a developer option to simulate an escenario.

What I used to clean back stack, in your case only activities B and C, is to register a broadcast on that activities and launch an intent from D activity when the user presses the button.

```
public void onClick(View v){
 Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
 broadcastIntent.setAction("com.package.CLEAR_B_C");
 sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
```

So when B and C recieve the intent, call finish().

[See that post and the answer from Francesco Laurita](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007998/on-logout-clear-activity-history-stack-preventing-back-button-from-opening-l)

Comment: i have already done this. but the issue with this approach is that i register an broadcast in onCreate() of B and C and i unregister it in onDestroy() so when B&C go in background wiht this developer option the ondestroy is called and the reciver is unregistered and hence the activities can not get the intent.

Comment: The same will happen in any application with this option enabled, it is only for developing purposes that simulate a real case when the android system kills your activities because he is running out of memory or whatever. It destroys every activitiy that you leave, in that case no intent will be recieved of course.

Comment: so does that mean  we can not have this functionality working in all scenarios? Because android can kill an activity anytime it runs low on memory.

Comment: Not in yours, all activity is destroyed when you are starting a new one, so no previous activity is saved on the back stack (you can see it using the command `adb shell dumpsys activity`) and you will be never able to mantain activities A->D. **Do not keep  activities** it is usefull to test if your app will recover the data saved on an activity killed. A solution, in addition to what I posted before, can be to overwrite the function `onBackPressed()`and add an intent to A with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.