# Clearning Stack of Activities unto the Top

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to perform a logout function in which I want to clear all the activities before the logout and start a new Login Activity

Here is my code

```
Utilities.logoutPlayerDefaults(Profile.this);
Utilities.vibrate(Profile.this);
Intent myIntent = new Intent (Profile.this,FBLogin.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

But it doesn't work. If i press back button i go back to Profile

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12468288/936414

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following way,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
   Intent myIntent = new Intent (Profile.this,FBLogin.class);
   myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
   myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(myIntent);
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: well you havent mentioned API Level in your question.

Comment: back button is meant to work the way it is designed for. why would you override the functionality. you have action bar and navigation drawer to help you.

Comment: @Raghunandan If i should press backBtn the app should close instead of showing last activities. I want to clear the Activity Stack at logout

Comment: @MuhammadUmar, Why dont you use `finish()` method ?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar use action bar on click on app icon navigate to home screen and press back button to exist. I had a long discussion on so with other developers and i went through the docs and i felt using action bar was right and back button is suppose to take you to the previous screen, also no where in the docs they suggest overriding back button functionality

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to below :

```
Utilities.logoutPlayerDefaults(Profile.this);
Utilities.vibrate(Profile.this);
Intent myIntent = new Intent (Profile.this,FBLogin.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: @Muhammad Umar check my answer perhaps you are not calling finish in your activity so in pressing back button you are getting profile activity.

Comment: Tried didn't work. Actually let us say we have MainMenu>Profile nOW If I logout to Profile and then do finish and then go to FBClass then only Profile get out of the way and if i press back i will go to MainMenu. Which is not what i want, i want the app to close if i go back i-e no Activity before FBLogin.