# How to logout and back on first activity when there is 5 activities between?

Tags: android

I need to add some security mechanism to android app, if user didn't click for more then two minutes I need to logout user. My question is if user has login and pass through for example 5 activities (none can call finish(), all are on stack) how to logout and back on first activity ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Also, check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007998/on-logout-clear-activity-history-stack-preventing-back-button-from-opening-l/9580057#9580057)

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be the following.

You start every of your activity via `startActivityForResult` and you start a timer in every activity on `onResume`. If the 2 minute elapses, then you use `setResult` to inidcate the timeout for the parent activity. In the parent activities you use `onActivityResult` to handle the incoming message (if there's any) and if it equals logout (insert any constant you define) then you do the same for those activities sending back to the original Main activity.

If the 2 minute elapses you have to call `finish()` sometime you cant avoid that. Or show a dialog that the user got logged out and get interaction.