# How to close an Android app from non-root activity by pressing the backbutton

Tags: android, authentication, exit, activity-lifecycle

The functionality I want to model in my Android app is, that if the user does login, he gets forwarded to the main menu (`MainMenuActivity`). From here and everywhere else where I provide a button for it in the app, he must be able to logout, which should send him back to the login screen (`LoginActivity`) and finish all the activities above on the stack. I achieve this by not destroying the LoginActivity after a login and at logout calling:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    // Clean up all other activities.
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
    startActivity(intent);
```

Also I want that the user can not go back with the backbutton form the main menu to the loginscreen. So I did overwrite the method `onBackPressed()` in my `MainMenuActivity`. Instead I want that when the user is pressing the backbutton from the main menu, the app does terminate (just like its the last activity on the stack). **How can I achieve this?**

I did read about several other approaches, for example finishing the LoginActivity after the login was performed and then later do it like described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3008684/1332314

But I'm not quite sure if this is a proper solution, just read the comments below the post.

Comment: are u using api level 11+?

Comment: 14+ actually, so I don't know if what I just posted will be useful for everybody. If you know a better solution for this high API level, just let me know.

Comment: check my answer. just set that flag whenever you start login or mainmenu activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this flag when you move to `MainMenuActivity`:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

this will delete all the previous activity and if you press back app will be closed.

Now in case of logout button do the same thing when you move to `LoginActivity` same flag will now make LoginActivity as the only activity on the stack and on back app will be closed.

Comment: Up to now the nicest and most clean approach I think. If I'll experience drawbacks, I'll let you know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I did find a solution to my problem. I just start the `MainMenuActivity` from the `LoginActivity` like this:

```
private void continueToMainMenu() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Then, when the user presses the backbutton in the main menu, this overwritten function gets called:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(LoginActivity.ACTION_QUIT);
    finish();
}
```

This will at first set a resultcode for the `LoginScreen` and then finish the `MainMenuActivity`. Then the `LoginActivity` does terminate receiving this particular resultcode, which I implemented like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == LoginActivity.ACTION_QUIT)
    {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Doing it this way will ensure not to touch too deep into the activity lifecycles, all the callbacks to clean up will still be called and it should not open any security leaks.

Hope this helps if anyone else will bump into the same issue.

Comment: Sure did help! Was worried I would have to write a lot of Interface code just to catch the result from another activity (a mandatory input dialog)

Comment: Would not recommend this as a general solution as user may have entered your app from another app.  If that's the case, the user would expect tapping back to bring them back to the app which opened your app.  Instead I recommend what @vipul mittal recommended, which rewrites the history so the back button behaves as the user expects

Comment: Yup, I didn't consider this, but anyway I thought his answer was more clean. That's why I accepted it a long while ago.