# How to Clear the activity stack SDK < 11

Tags: android, stack-trace

I need to clear the activity stack. All the activity except the current one in SDK 8. I want after logout from any activity I can reach to the Login Activity and All previous Activity will get Removed from the activity stack. 
I have tried this solution

```
 Intent i = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
```

But it is not working. I can't use finish() because user can logout from any activity.

Your Help is Highly appreciable.

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   startActivity(i);
I am using this code. It should start LoginActivity and Clear the stacktrace but instead I can go to the previous activities.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have got two Beautiful solution of my problem.

**SOLUTION 1:**

One is by using Broadcast Receiver. That I can broadcast a message to all my activity and onRecive() I can finish all my activity. As this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007998/on-logout-clear-activity-history-stack-preventing-back-button-from-opening-l/3008684#3008684) says.

**SOLUTION 2 (A Much Easier way):**

Second is by managing a flag in ShearedPrefrences or in Application Activity. In starting of app (on splash screen) set the flag = false; OnLogout click event, just set the flag true and in OnResume() of every activity check if flag is true then call finish().

It works like a charm :) And please If you can't answer at least don't abuse the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this flag on its own `Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

Comment: This flag supports SDK level 11 I need for SDK 8.
[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)

Answer (score 0):

Use This 
Normally when we launch new activity, it’s previous activities will be kept in a queue like a stack of activities. So if you want to kill all the previous activities, just follow these methods

> `Intent i = new Intent(OldActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
>   // set the new task and clear flags
>   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
>   startActivity(i);`

Comment: This flag supports SDK level 11, I needed it for SDK 8, Please check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK). Anyways I have solve this problem. I have posted my answer too.