# How to prevent user to go on previous activity after logged out in android using broadcast receiver?

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast

I'm trying to make simple Login App using firebase as a backend, but I stuck on a problem that how to prevent user to go back on previous activities. So when I searched then I got the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007998/on-logout-clear-activity-history-stack-preventing-back-button-from-opening-l). But this time my app is running properly without any issue or crash but Logcat is saying to unregister the Broadcast Receiver.So I go through the Android official docs but I'm unable to do that. So please anyone help me out. The code has been given below.

Thanks in advance.

**CODE FOR SENDING BROADCAST**

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();                            
broadcastIntent.setAction("com.android.login.ACTION_LOGOUT");
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

**CODE FOR RECEIVING BROADCAST**

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("com.android.login.ACTION_LOGOUT");
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("onReceive","Logout in progress");
            //At this point you should start the login activity and finish this one
            finish();
        }

    },intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before `finish();` call `unregisterReceiver(this);`

Comment: Still getting the same problem but this time activity is not changed from logout activity to sign-up activity. Previously it happening.